# email issue with spring and java mail api

Tags: spring, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

My application is now running in websphere 6.1 in AIX box, in which there is a email notification module which works fine till today. The same application is now getting migrated to a Tomcat based cloud platform which is running in a Linux server. The emails are getting sent out from the new Linux based platform to intended recipients, but the email is looking weird with no subject, no recipient email address, attachments are not proper, etc.

Previously it is ant-based build and now i build the project with maven. And i tried to keep same versions of spring and mail api jars.

What could be the issue and what am I doing wrong here? There are no exceptions while sending the email and it is really hard to identify the issue. Appreciate your help and Thanks in advance.

[image: Generated Email with no to, subject, attachment]
code:

```
  public synchronized void sendwithAttachment(MailMessage mailMessage) throws MailException, MessagingException {
        String methodName = "sendwithAttachment";
    LogManager.info(LogConstants.NOTIFICATION,
            Constants.ENTERING_METHOD + methodName, this.getClass());
    try{
        MailSender MailSender = (MailSender) mailSender;
        Session session = MailSender.getSession();
        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(new MimeMessage(session), true, "UTF-8");
        message.setFrom(mailMessage.getFrom());
            message.setTo(mailMessage.getTo());
               message.setSubject(mailMessage.getSubject());
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        message.setText(mailMessage.getText());

        DiskFileAttacher[] diskFileAttachments = mailMessage.getDiskFileAttachments();
        for (int i = 0; ((diskFileAttachments != null) && i < diskFileAttachments.length); i++) {
            message.addAttachment(diskFileAttachments[i].getAttachmentFilename(), new File(diskFileAttachments[i].getFilePath()));
        }
        InMemoryFileAttacher[] inMemoryFileAttachments = mailMessage.getInMemoryFileAttachments();
        for (int i = 0; ((inMemoryFileAttachments != null) && i < inMemoryFileAttachments.length); i++) {
            if(inMemoryFileAttachments[i].getFileObj()!=null){
            message.addAttachment(inMemoryFileAttachments[i].getFileName(),
                    inMemoryFileAttachments[i].getFileObj() );
            }else{
            message.addAttachment(inMemoryFileAttachments[i].getFileName(),
                    inMemoryFileAttachments[i]);
            }
        }
        List mimeMessageList = new ArrayList();
        mimeMessageList.add(message.getMimeMessage());
        MimeMessage[] mimeMessages = (MimeMessage[]) mimeMessageList.toArray(new MimeMessage[mimeMessageList.size()]);
        LogManager.info(LogConstants.NOTIFICATION,"before MailSender.send is called " + methodName, this.getClass());
        MailSender.send(mimeMessages);
    }catch(MailException e){
        LogManager.info(LogConstants.NOTIFICATION, "Some exception occured while sending emails...", this.getClass());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of JavaMail you're using.  If you're including the JavaMail jar file in your application, there may also be a copy of the GNU version of JavaMail on your Linux system that's being used instead of yours.  Look for the libgnumail-java package.

Comment: Thanks Bill for answering. The issue is relatively similar with another mail jar with maven dependencies and it is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and resolved this. I include maven dependency for axiom jars, which has also dependency for "geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec" and this geronimo java mail jars are also downloaded. And while sending emails this geronimo mail api was used instead of original java mail api. I added exclusions and now it is resolved.